# Vim autoindents too far for anonymous R function with lapply

Tags: r, vim, indentation

Vim autoindents too far (more than 4 spaces) for the following R code:

```
lapply(1:10, function(x){
       Something here
})
```

How can I fix this?

Here is a picture:

[image: Vim autoindents too far with an lapply]

Here is a minimal .vimrc which replicates this behaviour when editing files with a .R extension:

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set ts=4 sw=4
```

Comment: I don't think vim defaults to indenting at all (at least it doesn't when I test it). What sort of extensions/options have you turned out to make that happen?

Comment: I've added a minimal .vimrc that replicates this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution:

Adding

```
let r_indent_align_args = 0
```

to my .vimrc fixed the problem. See :h ft-r-indent for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .vimrc option shiftwidth (for 2 spaces):

`set shiftwidth=2`

Source:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'shiftwidth'

Comment: Hi. Thanks but this isn't the answer - I intended to indent by 4 spaces but vim indented further (around 7). My shiftwidth is set to 4. I believe this is because Vim is using the position of the word "function" relative to the curly bracket to inform the indentation, and in this case function comes after an lapply.

Comment: Did you set others options like expandtab, smarttab and tabstop?

Comment: I've added a minimal .vimrc that replicates this behaviour